# onActivityResult not being called after `finish()`-ing the called activity

Tags: java, android, androidx

I know, I know... This problem is all over SO already. None of those solutions worked for me / applied to me.

Here is how I try to do it.

From `LoginActivity` (Calling `Activity`):

```java
    private void loginSuccessful(LoggedInUserView model) {
        String welcome = String.format(getString(R.string.welcome), model.getDisplayName());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PinCodeActivity.class);
        if (!model.isNewUser()) {
            intent.putExtra("prompt", "Enter your pin");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 102);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("prompt", "Enter a pin");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 103);
        }
    }
```

Then in `PinCodeActivity` (Called `Activity`)

```java
    private void handlePinEntered() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("hash", pin.getValue());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        System.out.println("==================================="); // Is printed
        finish();
    }
```

Then `LoginActivity.onActivityResult()` EDIT: idk if important but it doesn't matter in my case whether `super.onActivityResult()` is called first or last. They both result in the same.

```java
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        System.out.println(requestCode); // Is NOT printed
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 101:
                    try {
                        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
                        // a listener.
                        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        loginViewModel.login(account);
                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
                    }
                    break;
                case 102:
                    System.out.println(data.getStringExtra("hash"));
                    break;
                case 103:
                    System.out.println(data.getStringExtra("hash"));
                    break;
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

This is how `LoginActivity` is defined

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "LOGIN";

    @Inject
    DaggerViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
    @Inject
    AppProperties appProperties;
    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    private ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;

    private EditText usernameEditText;
    private EditText passwordEditText;

    private Button loginButton;
    private SignInButton googleLoginButton;
    private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
// more code...
}
```

And finally how `PinCodeActivity` is defined

```java
public class PinCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private List<RadioButton> unchecked;
    private List<RadioButton> checked = new LinkedList<>();
    private PinCode pin = new PinCode();
// more code...
}
```

Here is the logcat

```java
2019-11-09 19:26:08.000 2462-2535/com.example.finance D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb761429ae0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7fb761418f40)
2019-11-09 19:26:08.009 2462-2535/com.example.finance D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb761429ae0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7fb761418f40)
2019-11-09 19:26:10.506 2462-2462/com.example.finance I/System.out: ===================================
2019-11-09 19:26:11.069 2462-2535/com.example.finance D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb761429ae0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7fb761418f40)
```

Note the line with all the `===` which is printed right before `finish()` and right after `setResult()` this means it was able to set the result.
Also I don't see signs of errors/crashes looking at those logs.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PinCodeActivity.class); I feel this should work

Comment: @PavanNagaraja I tried, unfortunately no luck...

Comment: everything looks fine for me don't know why onActivityResult not called  :|

Comment: First look into logcat, maybe child activity is crashing before setting result. Second validate if your onActivityResult is called with debugger. Third don't use System.out, use Log instead.

Comment: @3mpty I updated my post with the logcat and further details. I also verified with debugging that `onActivityResult()`is not called

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, PinCodeActivity.class);` What is 'this'? Does it point to your login activity? Try `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PinCodeActivity.class);`

Comment: @blackapps The first comment suggested the same. Also I stated that that method is defined in `LoginActivity` thus it points to `LoginActivity` which ofcourse is irrelevant because changing `this` to `LoginActivity.this` does and did not make a difference

Comment: `Also I stated that that method is defined in LoginActivity thus it points to LoginActivity`. Not necessarily. Sorry for overlooking the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is as the title says, onActivityResult() is not called from activity that I started with startActivityForResult()

Maybe it's just the way you phrased that, but your code doesn't clarify, so let's be clear. `onActivityResult()` should NOT be called "from activity that [you] started". `onActivityResult` is called *in the activity that you originally called `startActivityForResult` from*.

So your `onActivityResult` should be declared in `LogInActivity` NOT in `PinCodeActivity`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will clarify my post. I did not correctly understand how `onActivityResult()` was called. But it is in fact declared in `LoginActivity`

Comment: I'd suggest you post the FULL code to both activities to alleviate confusion, if you can. Further, strip the project down the minimum to illustrate the problem and share the whole project.